# How to get nationalities with django-countries

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get a nationality with a package called [django-countries](https://pypi.org/project/django-countries/) in Django, forexample if the country is **Germany** nationality is **German**, **Kenya** is **Kenyan** etc.

How can I achieve this with this package

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that package supports your issue but there are many Github repos that can help you.
here we have [demonyms.csv](https://github.com/knowitall/chunkedextractor/blob/master/src/main/resources/edu/knowitall/chunkedextractor/demonyms.csv) file
and [NATIONALITIES.py](https://gist.github.com/zamai/8e0d30a7f23f33e9c220c20db71c80dc) is here.

Comment: Isn't there a library which handle this ?